# How to reload edit options for widget in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, widget

I am building an iOS app that user can add new option for widget edit options
but the new option doest not show immediately
I have to wait few minutes for new option displaying
How can I reload option list for widget right now?

[image]

Comment: reload widget after changing the content

Answer (score 0):

```
import WidgetKit
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
    } 
}
```

reload widget when app enters background

Comment: Sorry, I tried it, but it not works

Comment: then your logic in getTimeLine function maybe wrong this the only way to reload widget when you change something in content in main app

Comment: you intent handler func is responsible for these titles that you provide it by coredata or by some structure i guess